# How to overcome poles?

Tags: modeling

[image]

Currently, this is the shape I have. I have added bevel weights and creases on the edges.
However, there is one edge where creasing / beveling / adding support loops create a lot of artifacts, and that is this selected edge below. [image]

I suspect this pole may be causing the issue
[image]

This is the result that I want, more or less (The edges still have a pinching effect so its not very good but you get the idea of how I want the edge to be). Also, it works in the picture below because i used a high level of subd. The reason im remaking this is so that i can get a less dense mesh.
[image]

Can anyone help guide me how to proceed on from here? As in how to make the edge look sharp without artifacts?

Here is the file [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe try this topology (create a bevel all along the edge that needs to stay sharp):

[image]

[image]

[image]